# Create 2 categories from 5 value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question. I am using mysql and I would like to update my table, i have 5 values (varchar) and i want to create 2 witch separate them. It is better pictured with an example. What is the best way?

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 day |
| 2 | on site |
| 3 | injured |
| 4 | heavy injured |
| 5 | null |

What i am looking for.

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | yes |
| 2 | yes |
| 3 | no |
| 4 | no |
| 5 | no |

it's mean that i want to update '30 day' and 'on site' to yes and the other ones to no.

Comment: This simply makes no sense.  Apart from the ids changing as well, why would you want to get rid of the current descriptions.  That just seems dangerous.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to create binary variables from the data I have for decision trees. The ids already corrected.

Comment: Probably more sense to just add another column for your Boolean values.

Comment: @konwes . . . Interesting.  Decision trees do not have a problem with either sequential or categorical variables (one of their strengths).  Translating these to a boolean seems *a priori* unnecessary for that purpose.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I build a model to predict fatal accidents. The variable being explained is mortality, which is why I need it to be yes or no.

Comment: "i want to update '30 day' and 'on site' to yes and the other ones to no" - Are you sure? Do you really want to *update* your table, so it only contains yes or no? You will never be able to tell afterwards whether a 'yes' means '30 day' or 'on site'. Don't you rather just want to *select* a 'yes' or 'no' depending on what the table row contains?

Answer (score -1):

This requires an update statement.

```
UPDATE table #here you select the table to be updated
SET description = #here you're giving instructions for the SET statement
    if (description IN ('30 day', 'on site'), 'yes', 'no')
```

in this last line you're defining the logic for updating.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it